# REGEX - removing stuff around something?

Tags: java, regex

I have a big ol' HTML file filled with stuff.

Somewhere in that file, there's a line like this

```
<span class="xcomponent">pls do not delete me</span>
```

I need to get rid of the  stuff but leave what is in between.

I'm using Java, and I assume the right approach is regex - I just don't really have enough experience with regex to pull this one off.

If it's any help, here's my 'stab in the dark' at it.

```
.*?(<span class="xcomponent">.*?</span>).*?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<span class="xcomponent">(.*?)</span>");
Matcher m = p.matcher(html);
m.replaceAll("$1");
```

Comment: Thanks. By the way, what does the $1 mean in this context?

Comment: @guywhoneedsahand, `$1` matches the first capture group (in parenthasis).  The stuff matched by `(.*?)`

Comment: Should there be quotes around $1 ?

Comment: @Atreys. Yes, I just added the quotes. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
myString.replaceAll("<span class=\"xcomponent\">(.*?)</span>", "$1")
```

Answer (score 0):

I write that from my memory, so there will be some msalle errors:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*?(<span class="xcomponent">pls do not delete me</span>).*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(yourLine);
if (matcher.matches()) { yourLine = matcher.group(1); }
```

Feel free to move brackets in the regexp indise the tag if you want to get rid of it too and leave only the inner text.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the line looks always like

```
<Something>WHATYOU WANT</closeSomething>
```

and you don't care about the something. Than the regex looks like:

```
<.*>.*</.*>
```

With this line you just use matcher to be sure the line contains the pattern from above.
Now you just use the split method and split at each < and >

```
string.split("<|>")[2]
```

either the first second or third is what you wanted. I didn't test it if wrong just play a bit.